# Extracting DNA from a kiwi

Tags: dna

I have two questions regarding this experiment.

1. Online instructions say to use 5g washing up liquid, 2g salt and 100ml tap water mixed together with a mashed up kiwi. Do I use a full kiwi ?
2. Instructions say to use coffee filter paper or a fine sieve. Would laboratory filter paper work or would it be too fine ?

Also, how can I improve on this method to get maximum yield etc ? All advice and suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, a full kiwi. The method is rather crude and the yield you get is not so high, because you will not break up all cells and also loose some of the DNA which is bound to the cell debris.
2. Lab filter paper of course works as well, as would a fine cloth (cheese cloth for example). The receipe is designed to work with stuff that people have usually in their kitchen, which is true for coffee filters, but usually not for laboratory filter paper ;-)

Comment: Great , and how would I increase the yield ?

Comment: With household chemicals? I don't think this will bring much. This is a demonstration and for this purpose it works pretty well. We have done this with bananas.

Comment: While it wouldn't increase the yield, I used isopropyl alcohol to precipitate (and thereby increase visibility) of extracted strawberry DNA.  Admittedly this was in a group setting (~10) so the total yield was higher, but I was could still scoop up small globs of visibly white DNA clumps in pill bottles without magnification or undue effort